# American Novels in Colloquial Language

Tags: american-english, formality, colloquialisms, north-american-english

I would like to know the names of novels that uses a lot of American colloquial expressions and idioms and it would be great if the novel portrays the exact way people talk in normal circumstances. I'm pretty aware that almost all fictional works arises from some form of day-to-day experiences. However, I hope you would've found that one novel or many novels that after you read, you felt like "Wow, that portrayed my life around me pretty well."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much anything by Twain, of course.  Jack London, <strike>D.H. Lawrence,</strike> James Ellroy, and Jay McInerney all used substantial amount of colloquial speech in their writing.

Comment: I don't think D.H.Lawrence used any American idioms did he? There were four-lettered words which would have been familiar to Americans, but his colloquial speech was that of the Nottingham coal-mining villages. If you are looking for an American of that period Steinbeck is the obvious one.

Comment: Sorry, I missed "American".